# Change the way to input elements to a Matrix - Java using Scanner

Tags: java, format

I want to add elements to a small integer array,but the data is entered line by line.Is there any way I can change how I input data.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int matrix1[][] = new int[2][3];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter elements for the 1st matrix : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            matrix1[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to change or a new method to input data, so instead of entering line by line I can enter them as a rectangle? ex.

```
no1  no2
no3  no4
```

When we normally get user inputs we can enter only 1 value to a line and here I would like to know if I could add more than 1 input per line,and assign those inputs to an array

Comment: Scanner doesn't generate output but handles input. Please show your missing code responsible for output generation (I am assuming you have it since your current code wouldn't even compile, not to mention generate any result).

Comment: I updated the code, is there a way to change the way I input numbers instead of doing it the typical Scanner way? @Pshemo

Comment: I doubt that problem is in a way you read input. From what I see in [first version of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35258359/1) it lies in code responsible for generated output which you are not showing us. Try reading answers found with query like https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20how%20to%20print%20out%20a%202d%20array and [edit] your question to include code responsible for printing, if you will still get some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this(have user enter 1 row at a time and specify the amount of rows & columns in advance):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the desired amount of rows for the matrix: ");
    int rows = s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the desired amount of columns for the matrix: ");
    int columns = s.nextInt();
    int[][] matrix = new int[rows][columns];
    System.out.println("Enter the matrix values one row at a time.");
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = s.nextInt();
    }
}
```

But add error checking(input validation).

Comment: Scanner introduced `nextInt` and other `nextFoo` methods to let us avoid `Integer.parseInt` and `split` methods.

Comment: You're right, better idea to use that, changed the code.

Comment: but here also I've to input numbers line by line, I want to try a method where i can input numbers to the position where they exactly are in the matrix!(I'm sorry if I sound stupid I 'm new to java)